# Postgresql connection via terminal - pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, connection, postgresql-9.1

I have a problem connecting (using SSH) to my virtualbox(ubuntu) postgres server.
I set up all nice and correctly.

PostgreSQL settings:

- `postgresql.conf` -> Allowed all incomming connection (*) and set ssl TRUE
- `pg_hba.con`f -> after a lot of changes i came to the point where it seems to work with this settings:

IP4

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
host all all 192.168.x.x/32 trust 
hostssl all all 192.168.x.x/32 trust
```

I tried:

1. Made restart of my postgres server on the virtual machine.
2. Then i went to my host machine (Snow Leopard), build a ssh connection to the virtualbox (ubuntu) and it's working.
3. ping my guest machine on port 5432 also works.
4. Open pgadmin on my host machine (Snow Leopard) -> added server 192.68.56.1 and database `pluto`, user `pippo`. The connection worked and i see the DB.
5. Tried open TERMINAL in Snow Leopard and executed following cmd:

   ```
   psql -h 192.168.56.1 -U pippo -d pluto
   ```

   with ERROR:

   ```
   psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.56.1", 
                 user "pippo", database "pluto", SSL off
   ```

I also tried to connect through my Java Program ans I got the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be warned: pgadmin3's (1.16) SQL editor is as responsive as typing 100 words per minute over a 50 baud modem. Should be fine for LAN.

Comment: What is listen_addresses set to in postgresql.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pgAdmin` tries to connect with and without SSL by default.

I suspect that you only try to connect *without* SSL via `psql`, while the server seems to require SSL for connections. Try:

```
psql "sslmode=require host=192.168.56.1 dbname=pluto" pippo
```

[More about `sslmode` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLMODE)

Comment: I get the following error msg: psql: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

Comment: I would set `log_statement = all`, connect with pgAdmin and psql and check the server logs to find the difference. There must be something that is not in your question. Are you connecting from the same machine, the same IP 192.168.56.1 is visible to both?

Comment: I am connecting to the same machine, assigned to the VM a static IP Address 192.168.56.1, i can ping this address from the host machine, so it is visible, also on the port 5432...

Comment: Used log_statement = all, but i can not see any things what looks diff. The connections string is: 2013-02-05 21:25:50 INFO   : Opening connection with connection string: dbname='pluto' user='pippo' password='XXXXXX' port=5432 sslcompression=0 application_name='pgAdmin III. Browser'

Comment: @Patric: Do you see the failed attempts from psql in the log? If not, you may be trying to connect to a different server .. (You don't need `log_statement = all` to check that.)

Answer (score 0):

Open my query into pgAdmin from command line:

**-f** The file containing your SQL script to be loaded in the query window

**-qc** The connection string without password (you can also use ssl connections)

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pgAdmin3.exe" -f "C:\slqFiles\FindFunctionByName.sql" -qc "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=myDatabase user=postgres"
```

The password will be collected from the **password** file located in the application folder:  *%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf*

You need **permissions** for connection. Try to add to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data\pg_hba.conf next line:

*host all                      all             ::/0                 trust*